# How to add a decommissioned node in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I just did nodetool decommission and it removed the node and I am trying to add it back in so I just started cassandra(decomissioned node) again but it doesnt seem to join the cluster?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other nodes will remember that the host ID you decommissioned should no longer be part of the cluster and will refuse to talk to it.

So if you want that machine to rejoin the cluster, you have to make it look like a new empty node so that the remaining nodes will let it rejoin. The easiest way to do that is to clear out all the data on the decommissioned node so that it will generate a new host ID for itself. Then it should be able to rejoin.

To clear out the old data, do this:

Stop Cassandra on the node, then:

```
rm -r <the commitlog_directory specified in cassandra.yaml>
rm -r <the data_file_directories specified in cassandra.yaml>
rm <the contents of the saved_caches_directory specified in cassandra.yaml>
rm <old logfiles in /var/log/cassandra/>
```

Then restart the Cassandra service

Comment: I experienced this with apigee cassandra datastore CRD. in this case you can delete PVC and delete the pod, K8S CRD will bring up the the clean pod and join to the ring.

Answer (score 3):

First stop the cassandra on decommissioned node and start it with below command:

$ sudo cassandra -Dcassandra.override_decommission=true

it will again join the cluster.

Comment: Does this really help? The accepted answer gives an explanation why this could not be enough...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rejoin the node with decommission command. What basically happened is you removed the node from cluster and token got redistributed. You need to reinitialize that node and let it join the cluster. Did you let the node finish streaming the data when you executed decommission?

Comment: yes decommission was successful. How do I reinitialize that node?

Comment: I thought reinitializing is just start that cassandra node again. no?

Comment: Can you share what error messege you are getting when you start the node again ?